# SQL trim dimension values from string

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way to remove part of string that is after multiple spaces depending on a character location? in this case a decimal.

Example: I would like to remove the "#.###" from all variations..

```
      "RANDOM DATA...         #.###" 
   or "RANDOM DATA...          .###" 
   or "RANDOM DATA...     .###X.###" 
   or "RANDOM DATA...   #.###X#.###"
   or "#.###         RANDOM DATA..."
   or ".###          RANDOM DATA..."
   or ".###X.###     RANDOM DATA..."
   or "#.###X#.###   RANDOM DATA..."
```

The dimension could be at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: yeah, use `REPLACE`: REPLACE(SomeColumn,'#.###','')`

Comment: I don't get your question.  What are you trying to remove in the last four lines?

Comment: The # could be any number 1-9.I should have mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: yeah, you should edit your question

Comment: And number have the same number of digits?

Answer (score 0):

Would replace would work? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Just replace 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'.' with nothing

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```